# `method_missing': undefined method `active_record' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration - Rails with MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, devise

Am using mongoDB and I create rails new app.

```
rails new app_name --skip-active-record
```

I used

```
gem 'mongoid', '~> 5.0.0.beta', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'devise'
```

When i am trying `rails g devise:install`, it raise an error

> `method_missing': undefined method`active_record' for # (NoMethodError)

And config/application.rb

```
require "rails"
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
```

Need Help.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your app, you skip active_record - then later on you get an error that it can't find active_record.

Have you tried creating the app without the --skip-active-record flag?

**Edit:**

Looks like [you were right to skip active record](https://gorails.com/guides/setting-up-rails-4-with-mongodb-and-mongoid), but you forgot to run `rails g mongoid:config`